# Notification when sound starts in webview

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm developing a web-based radio player app. When the radio plays in webview I want to send a notification. How can i do this?
the webview codes:

```
webview = FindViewById(Resource.Id.webView1);
webview.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendWebClient());
webview.LoadUrl("http://www.jantiradyo.net/radio/app.php");
WebSettings webSet = webview.Settings;
webSet.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
```